# Where does the Linux events store snapshots?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am attempting to collect event snapshots based on the [kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/events.txt).

```
- snapshot

  This command causes a snapshot to be triggered whenever the
  triggering event occurs.

  The following command creates a snapshot every time a block request
  queue is unplugged with a depth > 1.  If you were tracing a set of
  events or functions at the time, the snapshot trace buffer would
  capture those events when the trigger event occurred:

  # echo 'snapshot if nr_rq > 1' > \
        /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_unplug/trigger

  To only snapshot once:

  # echo 'snapshot:1 if nr_rq > 1' > \
        /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_unplug/trigger

  To remove the above commands:

  # echo '!snapshot if nr_rq > 1' > \
        /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_unplug/trigger

  # echo '!snapshot:1 if nr_rq > 1' > \
        /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_unplug/trigger

  Note that there can be only one snapshot trigger per triggering
  event.
```

Unfortunately, the documentation says nothing about where the snapshots are saved.

Where are the snapshot files stored?

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about Linux tracing, but I got curious about your question and read throught the documentation.

In [ftrace.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt), it says that it is exposed using `tracefs`, but for compatibility with old system, it is also in `debugfs`.

So if you have `debugfs` mounted at `/sys/kernel/debug`, you can find the snapshots at `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/snapshot`.

And if you have `tracefs` mounted at `/sys/kernel/tracing` then also at `/sys/kernel/tracing/snapshot`.

Note that there are the global `snapshot` and `per_cpu/cpu*/snapshot`.